# when Adding Localization, Appstore saying Name Already Exists?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, app-store

Guys i am having a very small problem.

I have made an App name Litofinter. I wanted my App to have **Spainsh Localization** also as my client is from Spain.So what i have done that in my Litofinter.plist i added "**Spanish**" instead of "**English**" in the "**Localization native development region**". After that when i login to **iTunesConnect** to submit the app in Appstore i saw **Manage Localization**, so now i wanted to added Spainsh Localization there, but Appstore is saying "**App Name Already Exists**".But i wanted to submit it, so i submitted it Without that manage Localization.But my Client is Not able to see in Spainish Locale... What should i do now to have spainsh Localization?

I know i have done many Mistakes, but can anyone please correct them?
**First Image showing what i see on iTunes Connect :-**

[image]

**Second Image Showing what i have done in .plist**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no correlation between localizations in iTunes connect and the localizations in xcode. iTunes connect localizations are meant to be displayed in the appstore, while localizations in xcode are meant to be used on the device itself.

For example, you can localize your app in 20 languages, while leaving the app name & description in iTunes connect only in english. many developers do that.

Make sure your app contains Spanish, click on the project name from the left navigation, and check the "Localizations" section. you will also have to check that `Localizable.strings` and `InfoPlist.strings` exist and contain spanish version. You can view the file info (and add localizations) when you select the file and open the "File Inspector" via the main menu's "View" -> "Utilities" -> "File Inspector".

You can check it yourself by changing the language of your device to Spanish temporarily.

Comment: let me see somethings that you have said... then i will accept it.. :) Thanks by the way for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build separate application for each localization.

Just provide translated XIB and strings files in your project.

You don't have to create a spanish duplicate in iTC. From your english app just use the "Manage localization" button (from application summary) then "Add new language" to specify new language and corresponding medias (description, keywords, etc.).

(You'd better discuss this on Apple dev's forums as most of this might be subject to NDA.)

Comment: Sorry dude, i hope u didn't understand my Problem.I know that for different languages i don't have to build different Apps...Please read the Problem again and if u r still not getting it tell me i will make a little bit more clear to you. :)